# Proprietary graphics completely broken on MacBook Pro 7,1

Tags: nvidia, graphics, 16.04, macbook-pro

I just installed Xenial, and I attempted to install the proprietary NVidia drivers. However, when I rebooted, the system went to a black screen (not even the backlight was on) and I had to reinstall. This happens with all three of the available choices of drivers (304, 304 updates, 340).

I'm using a MacBook Pro 7,1 with a GeForce 320m inside. The Nouveau drivers eventually crash the machine after about six hours of uptime and aren't good while they're running anyway.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Mr. IRC Man.

I installed [Bumblebee](http://bumblebee-project.org/), and it now works except for the brightness control (for some reason nvidia-xconfig wasn't installed).